# Bug with UITextField inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a problem with some TextField inside a UITableViewCell; i got two textfield inside of the table cell, when I tap on the the textField everything works fine as you can see in this two screenshots

**1.**

[image]

**The number in red squares are my UITextField, when I tap on one of them it works fine**

[image]

**But when i click on the other textField the entire cell disappear like this**

[image]

I have an empty space after the click on the other textfield

I have no function implemented, only a function that change font and textColor

```
func setPickers() {
    self.hourPicker.delegate = self
    self.minutePicker.delegate = self

    hourPicker.textColor = theme.grey
    minutePicker.textColor = theme.grey
    hourPicker.background = UIImage()
    minutePicker.background = UIImage()
    hourPicker.textAlignment = .center
    minutePicker.textAlignment = .center
    hourPicker.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 48)
    minutePicker.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 48)
}
```

**This the cell in my storyboard**

[image]

**EDIT 2**
Look my graphic debug what shows before the bug

[image]

And after it

[image]

The cell is called `EventDetailFooterTableViewCell`

**EDIT 3**
Here is where I initialize the cellView for the footer

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "footerCell") as! EventDetailFooterTableViewCell

    cell.event = self.event
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.setView()

    cell.backgroundColor = theme.mainColor

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    var height: CGFloat = 180.0

    var calendar = NSCalendar.current
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")! //OR NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    let dateAtMidnight = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
    let todayLong = dateAtMidnight.millisecondsSince1970
    if let eventDay = event.dateTime?.millisecondsSince1970 {

        if eventDay >= todayLong {
            height = 280
        }
    }

    return height
}
```

Comment: What will happen when you tap on empty space on this cell? Mb you add some segue or a behavior via Storyboard?

Comment: Are you using UITableViewController?

Comment: No I am using an UITableView inside an UIViewController, when i tap on empty space in my cell nothing happens :/

Comment: I think its something that goes in conflict with endEditing of textField

Comment: It looks like keyboard show/hide event somehow influence on cell or table. Do you use some 3d library that automatically move up views when keyboard shown?

Comment: No 3rd part library, the tableViewCell it disappear not only from the screen, but also from the hierarchy, look my edit

Comment: Can you make View Debugging->Capture View Hierarchy after views "disappear" and add this screenshot in the post?

Comment: Yeah I did it on last edit :)

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with table view data source methods. Please show your numberOfRows and cellForRow methods here.

Comment: My FooterCell is inserted as a viewForFooterInSection, can be a problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a problem. You are using regular cell as section footer and there is why you see unpredictable behaviour. You should use UITableViewHeaderFooterView instead. It is if you really need such design. Better solution will be to remove footer and make it cell instead.

Comment: Oh i've never knew about UITableViewHeaderFooterView but i resolved removing footer and putting that as a normal cell; anyway thank you for your help